# How to edit software repository in an infobox on Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

I'd like to update the repository URL on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX)), but I could not find where it is set. How can I update it to https://github.com/josephwright/beamer ?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the {{[Template:Infobox software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_software)}} is way too sophisticated and automatically pulls data from here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q736623

You can fix it by either correcting WikiData or by adding

```
| repo = {{URL|whatever}}
```

to the parameter list of the info box.